# circle shape on Font Awesome in Bootstrap 4 on go to top button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome, bootstrap-4

On the bottom of my page I a using a scroll to top button with a Font Awesome icon. The up arrow has a background color with border: 50%  and a hover color. Ive searched all over and border 50% should make a circle shape but something is preventing it in this case. I want a simple circle background color over the icon.

[image: image with ellipse shape]

my code

```css
#Scroll {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: #5F9EA0;
  color: white;
  text-align:center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15x;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: .6;
}

#Scroll:hover {
  color: #004289;
  background-color: #FFE466;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="Scroll" title="Go to top"><i class="fa fa-2x fa-arrow-circle-up"></i></button>
<script>
// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        document.getElementById("Scroll").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("Scroll").style.display = "none";
    }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
    document.body.scrollTop = 0;
    document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
</script>
```

Comment: `border-radius:50%` won't magically make a circle, but an ellipse. You have to make sure the element has equal height and width, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the button square:

```
#Scroll {
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, although it didn't work exactly with that so I changed it to height: 3.25rem; width: 3.25rem; and its how I want it to appear now

Answer (score 0):

Try this css for the button:

```
#Scroll {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 30px;
    z-index: 99;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #5F9EA0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: .6;

    /* add this */        
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;

}
```